# How to use UI object inside an included view in Titanium Alloy

Tags: mobile, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have four files that look similar to these:

*index.xml*

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <View class="container">
            <View id="report">

                <!-- Adds a textfield for name entry -->
                <Require type="view" src="textfield" id="name"/>

                <Button id="checkNameValue" title="Check Value"  width="100" height="40" onClick="checkname"/>
            </View>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

*index.js*

```
function checkname(e) {
    alert("Your name is " + $.name.getView('nameTextField').value);
}
```

*textfield.xml*

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="nameView">
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

*textfield.js*

```
var nameTextField = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    hintText:"Type your name",
    height:40,
    width:300,
    top:20,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});

$.nameView.add(nameTextField);
```

When I try clicking the Button to read the name value, I get an error:

```
message = "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating $.name.getView(\"nameTextField\").value')";
```

What is going wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `nameTextField.value` inside textfield.js? or you can use `$.name.children[0].children[0].value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing textfield.js to

```
$.nameTextField = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    hintText:"Type your name",
    height:40,
    width:300,
    top:20,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});

$.nameView.add($.nameTextField);
```

Then your alert code should look like this

```
alert("Your name is " + $.name.nameTextField.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add your Textfield into the included file as well like

> textfield.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="nameView">
          <TextField value="" hintText="Type Here" id="textfield" />
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Now you can access the textfield easily into your index file as :

> index.js

```
alert($.name.textfield.value);
```